# Progress bar update in python

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I search in stackoverflow how to implement a ProgressBar in tkinter. This is the code:

```
def worker(x):

    return x+x
    #time.sleep(1)

def compute():

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    objects=range(1,10)
    for i, _ in enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(worker, objects), 1):
        #print("completed =" +str(i/len(listF)))
        scanned.set((i/len(objects)*100))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    frame = Frame(master = window)
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
    button2 = Button(master=frame,text="Start", command=compute)
    button2.pack()

    frame = Frame(master = window)
    scanned = IntVar()
    frame.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=10)
    progress = Progressbar(master=frame, orient='horizontal',maximum=100,  variable=scanned,mode='determinate')
    progress.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

I found that this should work, but not in my case because the bar is update to 100% all in a time and I can not see the intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I solve the problem adding a Thread. This is the code:

```
def worker(x):

    return x+x
    #time.sleep(1)

def precompute():

    t=threading.Thread(target=compute)
    t.start()

def compute():


    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    objects=range(1,1000)
    for i, _ in enumerate(pool.imap(worker, objects), 1):
        #print("completed =" +str(i/len(listF)))
        scanned.set((i/len(objects)*100))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    frame = Frame(master = window)
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
    button2 = Button(master=frame,text="Start", command=precompute)
    button2.pack()

    frame = Frame(master = window)
    scanned = IntVar()
    frame.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=10)
    progress = Progressbar(master=frame, orient='horizontal',maximum=100,  variable=scanned,mode='determinate')
    progress.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```